# Border formatting of SSRS row group

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

This is my report.
[image]

Above row contains a parent row group and a child row group. 
I have done border formatting of the report . I simply right click each Text box and gives border accordingly. But, I am not able to set border for entire Group. In group properties there is no option for Border. I do not want any border between the rows of a group. How I can do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go inside the textboxes you want to remove the borders and remove the top and bottom border.

When the group expands, you will see the bottom border of the first textbox outside the group in the top and the top border of the first textbox outside the group below it. (but in between cells from the same group, there will be no borders)

Comment: This does not work, removing the top and bottom borders makes the entire column have no borders

Comment: @krilovich this was written a while ago, but I think the trick is to have one cell on each side, outside the group cell, where the bottom border (top cell) and top border (bottom cell) are visible. Then the group cell have no top/bottom border, but SSRS will still display the borders from the cells outside the group.

Comment: Hey Joao, yes that is what i ended up doing. I removed the top and bottom borders on the group rows and added a row underneath the group with a bottom border only

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to set the border to the Row header you shouldn't use the border property of the Row detail. 
The reason you wont see the changes on the bottom row header is because it overlaps with the top border of the row details. 
A good way to work around it is as follows :
you can set the color and border width of all three sides(Top, Left, Right) of the row header and see the change in the preview. However, even after you change the color of the bottom border value you wont see the change until you start scrolling down. IN most cases the visibility is not good even o[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDhAQ.jpg)n the printed version of the report. 
solution : change the border width of the bottom border width property  to be greater than the default or the detail top border width property.

caution : if you change the top border property of the detail columns it will repeat through out the details.

eg.
 Row header border property :

Border color Black
Border width 1pt, , , , 2pt

Row detail border Property :

Border color LightGrey
Border width 1pt