# Why can't I add border around Group in Report

Tags: reporting-services, border, ssrs-2008-r2

I have spent hours trying to add a border between the groups in my report and I am obviously missing something very simple.

My Report:
[image]

I have set it up with a parent group, child group, and details.
I need a darker or thicker line between each parent group instance (Every time the Company Name Changes).

At the moment it Renders like this:
[image]
with all the borders the same around every cell.

I have tried the suggestion from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617953/border-formatting-of-ssrs-row-group/12619892#12619892](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617953/border-formatting-of-ssrs-row-group/%2012619892#12619892)
(post with suggestion to add extra row outside of group with a border and remove 
borders from details) but ended up with thick borders around all cells.

I Tried selecting the Row Group and adding the following into the Border

```
IIf(Fields!Name.Value=First(Fields!Name.Value,"Tablix6"),"Solid","Nothing")
```

(added to BorderStyle Top)

```
IIf(Fields!Name.Value=Last(Fields!Name.Value,"Tablix6"),"Solid","Nothing")
```

(added to BorderStyle Bottom)

This generated an error message that the Iif statement could not do that many Options.

I tried the codes with different colours in the BorderColour just in case I was unable to see the difference in the rendering and with different thicknesses by altering the "Solid" to a colour/pt.
I also tried with Previous instead of Last but that also generated an error message around 'Previous not being supported'.

There are a lot of posts that suggest adding a group footer and adding the border to that and then minimizing the size of the group footer but I just cant seem to find how to add a group footer.  I cannot seem to get that as an option in the drop down menus.

I have looked at so many different posts on different sites that I now cannot see the wood for the trees and really don't know what to try next.  Please could anyone suggest where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Have just read a post stating that group footers can only be added in 2008r2 at the time of the group creation so will start again and advise if it has worked